# Linux Mint 13 (64) freeze with USB modem

Tags: linux, drivers, 64-bit, freeze, linux-mint

I have an iBurst modem and a driver I installed from here:

http://lelanthran.com/deranged/?p=132

I'm running Mint 13 (64 Bit) - so it's the 3.2 kernel version.

After plugging in the USB modem - it might work for a short while and then it will first freeze the USB and then freeze the entire system.

The output of my syslog after plugging in the modem is here:

http://pastebin.com/DNyqiwJi

I have also asked this question on the above website, but seeing as this bug might be related to USB and something not directly related, I thought I'd ask it here as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.